# jQuery: tiptip with jquery validation

Tags: jquery, plugins, tooltip

I'm using the standard [jQuery validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) for my form validation. And [Drew Wilson's tiptip plugin](http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/tiptip-jquery-plugin) for tooltips.

I'd just like to show a tiptip when there is an error instead of the validator's default callback.
How can I make a tiptip popup when there is an error?

Comment: C'mon. this and this? Help the internet archive out here, and put some info in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the validate plugin's [errorClass, errorElement, wrapper, errorLabelContainer, errorContainer, showErrors, success, errorPlacement, highlight, unhighlight, and ignoreTitle](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate) attributes to control how error messages are displayed.  Depending on how tiptip works I would recommend using these to create a tiptip via HTML and CSS that will be displayed properly.

P.S: errorPlacement should provide the most control over error placement, css class and HTML attributes used to create the error message.

Comment: Could you give me a little more? I'm not very good with javascript.

Comment: Take a look at the documentation. If you're already using the validation plugin you'll probably only need to read about DOM manipulation: http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/